# How to fix odd behaviour when doing :r TEST in vimtutor?

Tags: vim

I was going through Lesson 5 in vimtutor, and I had selected a part of lesson 5.3 in visual mode, and then done :w TEST as instructed in lesson 5.3.

In Lesson 5.4 however, I was told to do :r TEST, and so I did do that.
The text from the file TEST was indeed pasted right in to where I had the cursor.

However, when I tried to press the j key to move down further, something weird happened. The line after which I had my cursor on came up to the line I was working on (both these lines were from the pasted text from TEST file), the apparent line break gone.

Eg.

```
line before I press j
another line
```

became

```
line before I press janother line
```

for some reason.

What I've tried:

- pressing Esc. This results in literally nothing happening
- looking up Lesson 5.4 and read function of vimtutor and vim in Google and see if others had had this error. Nothing relevant came up.

Anyway, thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you hit `J` which does a « join » on the two lines.

Check your shift key/caps lock.